# $I $ is ideal. Prove $I=(0:1+I)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This is exercise 6.17 in *Steps in Commutative Algebra*:

> $I$ is ideal of the commutative ring $R$. Prove $I=(0:1+I)$.

I proved it wrong like this, let $r\in (0:1+I)$ then $r=r(1+0)=0$. So if the conclusion is true, then $I=0$. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: $1+I$ stands for the residue class of $1$ modulo $I$. (See page 21.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to prove that $I=(\overline{0}:_R\overline{1})$, where the residue classes are taken mod $I$.

If $r\in I$, then $r\cdot \overline{1}=\overline{r}=\overline{0}$ because by hypothesis $r\in I$, then $r\in (\overline{0}:\overline{1})$. This means that $I\subseteq (\overline{0}:\overline{1})$.

If $x\in (\overline{0}:\overline{1})$, then $x\cdot \overline{1}=\overline{x}=\overline{0}$, therefore $x\in I$. This means that $(\overline{0}:\overline{1})\subseteq I$.

Hence $I=(\overline{0}:\overline{1})$.